# Spark allows filtering/selecting on non-existing columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am encountering a very strange behavior - or at least a non expected behavior - using Spark SQL library version 2.2.1.
I have a simple dataframe:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("...")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [FIELD_A: string, FIELD_B: string ... 244 more fields]

val tmp = df.select("FIELD_A")
tmp: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [FIELD_A: string]
```

If I perform the following operations I get unexpected behaviors:

```
// the following line does not work (as expected)
tmp.select("FIELD_B").count()

// the following line WORKS (unexpectedly)
tmp.where($"FIELD_B" === "abc").count()
```

Why could I filter on non-selected columns, which should not be present in dataframe `tmp`? 
I could not find any reason or relative explanations on Internet.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see that happening (spark 2.3.1)

Comment: It doesn't happen in mine 2.2.1.

Comment: Interesting. I am using Spark 2.2.a on Zeppelin, but I don't think this makes any difference.

Comment: Spark 3.0.0 still has this problem. I'm not sure whether it's a problem, but it really confuses me...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the optimizer rearranges the `select` (Project) and the `where` (Filter) stages without checking first whether the original plan was actually valid.

```
scala> case class Foo(FIELD_A: String, FIELD_B: String)
defined class Foo

scala> val tmp = List(Foo("q", "w"), Foo("e", "r")).toDF
tmp: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [FIELD_A: string, FIELD_B: string]

scala> tmp.select("FIELD_A").where($"FIELD_B" === "r").explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('FIELD_B = r)
+- Project [FIELD_A#2]
   +- LocalRelation [FIELD_A#2, FIELD_B#3]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
FIELD_A: string
Project [FIELD_A#2]
+- Filter (FIELD_B#3 = r)
   +- Project [FIELD_A#2, FIELD_B#3]
      +- LocalRelation [FIELD_A#2, FIELD_B#3]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [FIELD_A#2]
+- Filter (isnotnull(FIELD_B#3) && (FIELD_B#3 = r))
   +- LocalRelation [FIELD_A#2, FIELD_B#3]

== Physical Plan ==
*Project [FIELD_A#2]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(FIELD_B#3) && (FIELD_B#3 = r))
   +- LocalTableScan [FIELD_A#2, FIELD_B#3]

scala> tmp.select("FIELD_A").where($"FIELD_B" === "r").collect()
res5: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([e])
```

Comment: which version of Spark are you using?
The problem is that in case of code like this:
{code}
tmp.select("FIELD_A").distinct().where("FIELD_B")
{code}
the result is inconsistent. I had a bug like this in the code and I was expecting Spark raising an error..

Comment: I tested on 2.2.1 and 2.3.1. This is a bug, I think. Especially if they still rearrange the `select` and the `where` if there's a `distinct` in the middle.

Comment: Right, and with groupBy as well. It looks very weird to me that nobody noticed that before (me included). Also, why other people with same version of Spark are not having the same issue?